# Django images not showing up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I've spent hours looking for a solution, figured I would post for myself. Django images won't show.

models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
...
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='item_pics')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ItemListView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', ItemListView.as_view(), name="site-home"),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html-file

```
{% extends "ui/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
<li>
<p><img src="{{ item.image.url }}"></p>
<br>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

It shows up like this:
[image]

When I copy image address, I get http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg

Comment: Post the relevant parts (i.e. `DEBUG`, `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`) of your `settings.py`. Did you double check that you have a file named `default.jpg` in your `MEDIA_ROOT` directory?

Answer (score 0):

There is no image at http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg. Are you sure the path is correct? You uploaded way too little code. It seems like it should be http://localhost:8000/item_pics/default.jpg? Does that link work?

If I'm right, try this in models.py:
`image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='media')`

Comment: I'm also having same issue, and my image needs to go to the folder images in static folder. static/images, how do I upload the images to this folder, when I add an image in the admin site?